# multiprocessing slower than normal single process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bigdata

I am new to multiprocessing and was suprised when I ran this simple example.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import timeit

data = np.linspace(1,100, num=1000000)


def f(x):
    return x*x

start = timeit.default_timer()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(2)
    multi = p.map(f, data)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print ("Multi: " + str(stop-start))

Nonmulti = np.zeros(len(data))
start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in data:
    Nonmulti[i-1] = f(i)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print ("Non multi: " + str(stop-start))
```

I get the following numbers with different number of processes and looking at Task Manager:

```
Multi:
Pool    Time    CPU_max
2       ~39     ~30%
4       ~42     ~30%
8       ~39     Sligthly over 30%

Non multi:
Time    CPU_max
14.5    11%
```

So I though, the multiprocessing would be faster than the for-loop as the pool was able to use more CPU and calculate several values simultaneously. Is it the spawning of several processes that is really time consuming, or is it something else? Is there something else I can use to speed up calculations on huge arrays?

Comment: How many cores does your CPU have?

Comment: CMD says i have four cores when i run the following line: WMIC CPU Get DeviceID,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors.  

When looking in Task Manager under performance it looks like i have 8 cores.

Comment: Ok.. And what exacly do you try to calculate? Square of each number in np.linspace(1,100, num=1000000) ?

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so note that **all** the code that is not contained inside functions should go inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. So you have to write `if __name__ == '__main__': data = np.linspace(...); start = ... ` and this `if` should also contain the non-multiprocessing version, otherwise the subprocesses will end up doing twice the work.

Comment: @Bakuriu can you explain us why is it? Where can I research about that?

Comment: @PatrykPerduta Because Windows lacks the `fork` system call. So when you create a subprocess you actually have to run from the start, which means the python interpreter will import the module in order to find the function, and as such code will be executed again. This is explained several times in the `multiprocessing` documentation.

Comment: In any case: I've done some tests using my linux laptop. Indeed in this case multiprocessing is like 3x slower, however if you modify `f` to do some heavier calculation, like `def f(x): return (x*x*x*x + x*x*x + x*x) ** 100` then the timings get closer.  I believe the reason you see this behaviour is simply because what you are dealing with is **not** "big data", but just average sized data and the overhead of IPC is too high.

Comment: Alright, thx for helping out Bakuriu. This was just an example I made to get to know how multiprocessing was working. In my real program I have some heavier calculations to do, maybe multiprocessing will be better there!